# Why is it when I add my own class next to 'container container-fluid', my width is larger than when I use ID on the DIV?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I put mainCont as a class so it looks like this 'container container-fluid mainCont' the div takes up larger width than when mainCont is set as ID like in the below code. Why is this? My guess is something to do with some bootstrap styling still taking precedence?

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  /*or 1 em*/
}

#mainCont {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgb(177, 175, 175);
}
```

```html
<div class='container container-fluid' id='mainCont'>
  <div class="row">
    <h1 id="twitchHead">TWITCH STREAMERS</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its about specificity - an Id has a greater specificity than a class - so when you have the id applied to the element - the style rules for that id trump the class based style rules.

You should load the bootstrap style sheet first and then simply write your style sheet after it - with or without the id. Note though that there is a fair use of !important in the Bootstrap CSS so it could be better to use the id for the greater specifitity.

Incidentally - in Bootstrap world, .container contrains the div to 1200 px and centers it (using margin:0 auto) whereas .container fluid allows the div to go the full width of the browser - you should use either one but not both.

Interesting reading on specificity and how its calculated
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap** `container` class have fixed width and `container-fluid` class have 100% width which wrapping whole device width. so its not a good idea to used both in same div!

example

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-* ">

   </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

#### or

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-*">

   </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: what is the fixed width of container class?

Comment: `max-width:1140px`